# Por qué se usa pretérito imperfecto en lugar de subjuntivo o condicional en algunas situaciones

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

En una película de Hollywood llamada "La Roca" (1996) vi una escena en la que Sean Connery dijo a su hija tras haberse fugado:

"*I have rehearsed this speech a thousand times on the chance that we would meet*"

En los subtítulos en español fue esto:

"*He ensayado este discurso mil veces por si **llegaba** el momento*"

Pregunta: ¿Por qué no se usó "llegue" o "llegara" o "llegaría" en lugar de "llegaba"?

También, desde una serie de Netflix "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España):

"*Si yo estuviera en tu lugar, diría que me amenazó con hacerme daño a mí y a mi familia si no **colaboraba**.*"

Pregunta: ¿Por qué no se usó "colaborara" o "colaboraría" en lugar de "colaboraba"? Claro que no se puede usar "colabore" porque podría ser una discrepancia entre "amenazó" y "colabore" (tiempo).

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en mi letra si haya algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La locución conjuntiva "por si" va seguida de indicativo, mientras que la locución (de similar significado) "en caso de que" va seguida de subjuntivo:

- He ensayado este discurso mil veces **por si llegaba** el momento.
- He ensayado este discurso mil veces **en caso de que llegara / para cuando llegara** el momento.

Lo mismo ocurre cuando la referencia es futura:

- Estoy ensayando este discurso **por si llega** el momento.
- Estoy ensayando este discurso **en caso de que llegue** el momento / **para cuando llegue** el momento.

Después del "si" condicional, nunca se usa el potencial "colaboraría". Podría usarse "colaborara" si fuera una condicional con prótasis en pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo y apódosis en potencial:

- Lo ayudaría si colaborara.

El punto es que la oración en cuestión es una versión en lenguaje indirecto de una oración condicional en lenguaje directo cuya prótasis está en presente y cuya apódosis está en futuro: cuando se pasa a lenguaje indirecto, el presente se convierte en pretérito imperfecto del indicativo (no subjuntivo) y el futuro se convierte en potencial.

Oración en lenguaje directo: Les **haré** daño a ti y a tu familia si no **colaboras**.

Oración en lenguaje indirecto: Me dijo que nos **haría** daño a mí y a mi familia si no **colaboraba** (o la versión: Me amenazó con hacerme daño a mí y a mi familia si no colaboraba).

Comment: entiendo. Interesante. Podría ser usado pretérito simple ("por si llegó el momento" y "...si no colaboré"?

Comment: Esos tiempos verbales son posibles, pero su sentido (y uso) es totalmente diferente, por ejemplo: Te aviso por si (ya) llegó el momento // Si no colaboré (si es un hecho que no colaboré), seré castigado.

Comment: También cabe destacar que la locución conjuntiva "por si" también puede estar acompañada con el subjuntivo imperfecto tal como se demuestra en este sitio https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/59483/mod_resource/content/1/condicionales%20otros%20nexos.pdf